# jsp with windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, jsp, datasource

i have a jsp page i am useing the test the dataconnection with sql server 2008 R2 using windows authentication
jsp page

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*, javax.sql.*, javax.naming.*"%>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Using a DataSource</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Using a DataSource</h1>
    <%
        DataSource ds = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = null;
        try{
          Context context = new InitialContext();
          Context envCtx = (Context) context.lookup("java:comp/env");
          ds =  (DataSource)envCtx.lookup("jdbc/confluence");
          if (ds != null) {
            conn = ds.getConnection();
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users ");
           }
         }
         catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error occurred " + e);
          }
          int columns=0;
          try {
            rsmd = result.getMetaData();
            columns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
          }
          catch (SQLException e) {
             System.out.println("Error occurred " + e);
          }
     %>
     <table width="90%" border="1">
       <tr>
       <% // write out the header cells containing the column labels
          try {
             for (int i=1; i<=columns; i++) {
                  out.write("<th>" + rsmd.getColumnLabel(i) + "</th>");
             }
       %>
       </tr>
       <% // now write out one row for each entry in the database table
             while (result.next()) {
                out.write("<tr>");
                for (int i=1; i<=columns; i++) {
                  out.write("<td>" + result.getString(i) + "</td>");
                }
                out.write("</tr>");
             }

             // close the connection, resultset, and the statement
             result.close();
             stmt.close();
             conn.close();
          } // end of the try block
          catch (SQLException e) {
             System.out.println("Error " + e);
          }
          // ensure everything is closed
        finally {
         try {
           if (stmt != null)
            stmt.close();
           }  catch (SQLException e) {}
           try {
            if (conn != null)
             conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {}
        }

        %>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

server.xml

```
<Context docBase="C:\Users\Kevonia\Desktop\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\wtpwebapps\P-CAT" path="/P-CAT" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:P-CAT">
          <Resource name="jdbc/confluence" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/P_CAT_teetws"
              maxActive="20"
              maxIdle="10"
              validationQuery="select 1" />
      </Context>
```

Error occurred org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Cannot open database "P_CAT_teetws" requested by the login. The login failed.)

Comment: Where is the Windows authentication exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check you post number from Sql server configuration Manager.. that error is say that it can't find that database on the current post number.also  use this as the url

url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/P_CAT_teetws;Integrated Security = true"